# Is there a solution to this system of equations?

Tags: divisibility, divisor-sum

Is there an integer solution to this system of equations?

$$\gcd(x, \sigma(x)) = 2x - \sigma(x) = \frac{x}{3} = \frac{\sigma(x)}{5}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the back end of your equation, if $\frac{x}{3}=\frac{\sigma(x)}{5}$, then $\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}=\frac53$.

This would imply that $5x$ is an odd perfect number.  (http://mcdanielabundancy.wdfiles.com/local--files/start/WeinerAbundDense.pdf)

This suggests that it would be hard to find such a number.

Answer (score 0):

Just a partial answer to my question:

$x = {3003}^2$ "satisfies" the system of equations, save up to only

$$\gcd(x,\sigma(x)) = 2x - \sigma(x) = \frac{x}{3}.$$

This solution corresponds to the only known Descartes / spoof odd perfect number.

> > Edit:  Well actually, $x = {3003}^2$ only satisfies up to
> >     $$\gcd(x,\sigma(x)) = 2x - \sigma(x) = 819 \neq \frac{x}{3}.$$

In general, by [paw88789](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147810)'s answer, since $5x$ turns out to be an odd perfect number, then we have $$x > 2\cdot{{10}^{1499}}$$
by Ochem and Rao's [result](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2012-81-279/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4/).

So, we have that $$\gcd(x,\sigma(x)) = \frac{x}{3} > \frac{2}{3}\cdot{{10}^{1499}}.$$

This makes a brute force search for such $x$ even harder.